# Creating drop down menu in html and css (strange error)

Tags: html, css, django

Before you read: please do not judge me on every little thing.  I am a beginner to this sort of thing and I am just trying to get some practice.  Only comment my mistakes if they are either relevant to the conversation or *truly* helpful.

I've looked over and over at my code and stackoverflow answers but nothing has what I need.  I want to create a dropdown menu (you hover on a button and multiple links appear in a vertical line below it).  I have been having trouble because the links are horizontal instead of vertical when I hover.  I have no idea why.  I thought this may be because the display style on my nav bar is set to inline, but I used id's in my css, so that should override the navbar classes.  I'm very confused.  Someone please help.  Here is the relevant code (yes, I am using django):

```
<style>
#dropdown {display: none;position: relative;background-color: #dde000; padding: 0px;z-index: 1; left: 970px; top:45px;}
#drop:hover #dropdown {display:block;}

div.navbar {border: 2px outset gray; position: relative; margin-left:-21px; height:45px; background: #dddddd; margin-top:-6px; left: 15px;}
.navbar a {height: 23px; display:inline; text-decoration: none; color: black; padding: 10px; float: left; background: #dddddd; padding-top:12px;}
.navbar a:hover {background: #eeeeee; transition: all 0.4s;}
</style>

<div class="navbar">
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:index' %}">Home</a>
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:create_post' %}">Create Post</a>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:login' %}">My Profile</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:login' %}" style="float:right; margin-right:50px;">Login</a>
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:register' %}" style="float:right; ">Register</a>
    {% else %}
                
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:logout' %}" style="float:right; margin-right:50px;">Logout</a>
    <div id="drop">
    <a style="float:right; margin-right: 50px;" >{{ user.username }}</a>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Edit:  Is the best way to do this just to take a few weeks to learn javascript?

Comment: If you want each link in your dropdown to be on a separate line, `display: inline` is indeed your culprit. Either make them a block element with `.navbar #dropdown a {display: block}` or put a line break (`<br>`) between them.

Comment: They have to be hidden until the mouse hovers on the #drop div.  And they are in display: block after that.  Look at line 3.  Also, putting a line break between them fucks up the page.  Bad.  I have no idea why.

Comment: An easy way to learn is to take working code and make small changes until fit your needs. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 things going on here:

The horizontal links on hover are popping up because you are basically floating the `a` tag to the right and not fixing the `#dropdown` with it so it gets left behind.

in order to get the submenus to show below, you have a number of methods for me I usually use `display: flex` your code would look something like this:

```
<style>
#dropdown {display: none;background-color: #dde000; padding: 0px;z-index: 1; left: 970px; top:45px;}
#drop {float: right; padding: 10px}
#drop:hover #dropdown {display:flex; ;
  flex-direction: column;}

div.navbar {border: 2px outset gray; position: relative; margin-left:-21px; height:45px; background: #dddddd; margin-top:-6px; left: 15px;}
.navbar a {height: 23px; display:inline; text-decoration: none; color: black; padding: 10px; float: left; background: #dddddd; padding-top:12px;}
.navbar a:hover {background: #eeeeee; transition: all 0.4s;}
</style>

<div class="navbar">
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:index' %}">Home</a>
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:create_post' %}">Create Post</a>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:login' %}">My Profile</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:login' %}" style="float:right; margin-right:50px;">Login</a>
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:register' %}" style="float:right; ">Register</a>
    {% else %}
                
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:logout' %}" style="float:right; margin-right:50px;">Logout</a>
    <div id="drop">
    <a style="margin-right: 50px;" >{{ user.username }}</a>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

you can refer here to more explanation  about [css flex here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

**Edit Code**

```
<style>
.navbar{display:flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
   width: 100%;
}
.navbar > a, .navbar> div{ 
align-content: flex-end
}
#dropdown {display: none;background-color: #dde000; padding: 0px;z-index: 1;}
#drop{display:flex; ;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#drop:hover #dropdown {display:flex;
  flex-direction: column; z-index: 1;  margin-top: 8px
}
div.navbar {border: 2px outset gray; height:45px; background: #dddddd}
.navbar a {height: 23px; text-decoration: none; color: black; padding: 10px;  background: #dddddd; padding-top:12px;}
.navbar a:hover , .navbar div:hover{background: #eeeeee; transition: all 0.4s;}
</style>

<div class="navbar">
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:index' %}">Home</a>
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:create_post' %}">Create Post</a>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:login' %}">My Profile</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:login' %}">Login</a>
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:register' %}">Register</a>
    {% else %}
                
    <a href="{% url 'blog_main:logout' %}">Logout</a>
    <div id="drop">
    <a style="margin-right: 8px;" >{{ user.username }}</a>
    <div id="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still having a couple of problems.  The links don't appear below the main button.  They're to the side.  Also, now whenever I hover over the main button, the rest of the website gets pushed down.

Comment: on my end, the elements were not being pushed down so it might be another css rule that you have but I modified the code please check if that is better